# ImportError: No module named garbage

Tags: python

Getting import error when i ran following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random.randn as randn
fig = plt.figure();
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(randn(1000).cumsum())
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-77-ed08747137ac>", line 1, in <module>
    fig

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py", line 251, in __call__
    self.finish_displayhook()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/displayhook.py", line 63, in finish_displayhook
    self.session.send(self.pub_socket, self.msg, ident=self.topic)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/session.py", line 626, in send
    stream.send_multipart(to_send, copy=copy)

  File "zmq/sugar/socket.py", line 329, in send_multipart
    self.send(msg, SNDMORE|flags, copy=copy, track=track)

  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 619, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:6169)

  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 673, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:6014)

  File "zmq/backend/cython/message.pyx", line 178, in zmq.backend.cython.message.Frame.__cinit__ (zmq/backend/cython/message.c:1586)

ImportError: No module named garbage
```

Then I try to find module named garbage,but it seems don't exist

Comment: I don't know either,but it just happened

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be fixed by running:

```
$ pip install pyzmq --upgrade
```

The version of pyzmq should be at least 14.1

```
>>> zmq.__version__
'14.1'
```